# change value of data member of one class from another class

Tags: c++, oop

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class B{
    public:
        int x;
        void setx(int a){
            x =a;
            cout<<"Inside set "<<x<<endl;
        }
        void show();
    };

    void B::show(){
        cout<<"inside show "<<x<<endl;
    }

    class A{
    public:
        void func();
        void func2();
        B bb;
    };
    void A::func(){
        bb.setx(100);
        bb.show();
    }
    void A::func2(){
        bb.show();
    }
    int main()
    {
       A a;
       B b;
       a.func(); 
       b.show(); 
       a.func2(); 
       return 0;
    }
```

Changes are applicable only to class A, where actual value in class B is not changing. I tried static but its showing error.

OUTPUT I'M GETTING :
Inside set 100
inside show 100
inside show 0
inside show 100

OUTPUT I WANT :
Inside set 100
inside show 100
inside show 100
inside show 100

Comment: Object `b` in `main` and object `bb` inside object `a` are two completely different objects. They are not related to each other. As such, changing `a.bb` does not do anything with `b` in `main`. The output you get is what you should expect.

Comment: Note that `b.show()` has undefined behaviour due to the indeterminate value of `b.x`. Always initialise your variables. And get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @molbdnilo Is it indeterminate? I thought default constructor zero-initializes all members (*but I can't remember the initialization rules for my life, so I might be wrong*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
int main()
{
   A a;
   B b;
   a.func(); 
   a.bb.show(); 
   a.func2(); 
   return 0;
}
```

You're calling `show()` on wrong object. Since `a` has it's own `bb`, you need to use `a.bb` to see change. `b` in `main` is different object (even if of the same class).

Answer (score 0):

A class is **not** an object. It is a **user defined data type** which can be accessed and used by creating an **instance** of that class. An instance of the class is an object.

Now, in your `main` function, when you instantiate an object of class `A` by writing `A a;`, the constructor of `class A` instantiates the data member `bb` (which is of type `B`). You then create another object of type `B` in your `main` function, by writing `B b;`. This instantiation of class `B` has nothing to do with the data member `bb` in your `class A`. To get your desired output, you would need `a.bb.show()`.

To be clear:

```
struct Airplane {};

Airplane a1, a2, a3;
```

I have 3 airplanes, which are each an instantiation of the `class Airplane`, 3 objects of type `Airplane`. Changing `a1` doesn't imply changing `a2` and `a3`.